# Checking a range against other ranges for exact matching

Tags: excel, vba, range

I need a macro to check the content of the cells in range J3:J21 againts the content of the cells in range A3:A21, B3:B21, C3:C21, D3:D21, E3:E21, F3:F21, G3:G21, H3:H21, I3:I21 and IF find a match in any of the columns (ranges) to:

1-st: add the content of the cell in row 2 to the content of the cell in row 1 (behind it) in that column and clear the content in the cell in row 2 of that column
2-nd: to add to row 2 of that column the content of J1 and J2
3-rd: to Delete column J
If no match is found to do nothing

Same check against the rest of the ranges to be performed for the cells in the range I3:I21, and after that H3:H21, and after that G3:G21, after that F3:F21, and after that E3:E21, and after that D3:D21, and after that C3:C21, and after that B3:B21, and after that A3:A21.

[image: Sample image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to happen when a match is found, but I get help you get to that point!

Press Alt-F11 to start editing VBA.

In the upper left window pane should be your workbook in **bold**. Right-click on it and insert a new module.

Paste in the following:

```
Option Explicit 'this line makes typos less likely in your code
'Private constants are unavailable outside of your module, which means that other code can have constants with the same names.
Private Const ROW_START = 3
Private Const ROW_END = 21
Private Const COLUMNS = 10

'Process the worksheet.
'Called by a button or something
'Calls ProcessColumn
Sub ProcessWorksheet(Optional sheetOrNothing As Worksheet)
    Dim iColumn As Integer
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    
    If sheetOrNothing Is Nothing Then
        Set sheet = ActiveSheet
    Else
        Set sheet = sheetOrNothing
    End If
    
    For iColumn = COLUMNS To 2 Step -1 'Step backards from column J to column B. (we don't need to analyze column A if I understand you correctly)
        ProcessColumn sheet, iColumn
    Next iColumn
End Sub

'Process a column in a worksheet
'Processes each cell and, if no match was found, deletes the column
'Called by ProcessWorksheet
'Calls fbProcessCell
Sub ProcessColumn(sheet As Worksheet, iColumn As Integer)
    Dim bNoMatchFound As Boolean
    Dim iRow As Integer
    
    bNoMatchFound = True
    
    For iRow = ROW_START To ROW_END
        If fbProcessCell(sheet, iRow, iColumn) Then
            bNoMatchFound = False
        End If
    Next iRow
    
    If bNoMatchFound Then
        sheet.Columns(iColumn).Delete
    End If
End Sub

'Looks for matches in previous columns
'Returns True if match was found and changes were made
'Returns False if no match was found in previous columns
'Called by ProcessColumn
'Calls DoMatchFound
Function fbProcessCell(sheet As Worksheet, iRow As Integer, iColumn As Integer) As Boolean
    'returns true if match was found
    
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim cellMatching As Range
    Dim value As Variant
    Dim iMatchingRow As Integer
    Dim iMatchingColumn As Integer
    
    Set cell = sheet.Cells(iRow, iColumn)
    value = cell.value
    
    If Not (IsEmpty(value) Or value = "") Then
        For iMatchingColumn = 1 To iColumn - 1
            For iMatchingRow = ROW_START To ROW_END 'Unclear... this guesses that you are checking against the entire column rather than just for that row. ??
                                                    'If you are doing it for an entire column, there are better ways to do this (e.g. Application.Match()) but get it working first, refactor second.
                Set cellMatching = sheet.Cells(iMatchingRow, iMatchingColumn)
                If value = cellMatching.value Then
                    DoMatchFound sheet, cell, iRow, iColumn, cellMatching, iMatchingRow, iMatchingColumn, value 'I couldn't figure out what you wanted to do here so I just thew in all arguments. ;-)
                    fbProcessCell = True
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Next iMatchingRow
        Next iMatchingColumn
    End If
    
    'if code gets here, no match was found
    fbProcessCell = False
    
End Function

'Changes the worksheet based on a found match
'Called by fbProcessCell
'Calls nothing
Sub DoMatchFound(sheet As Worksheet, cell As Range, iRow As Integer, iColumn As Integer, cellMatching As Range, iMatchingRow As Integer, iMatchingColumn As Integer, value As Variant)
    Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, "DoMatchFound", "Not written yet" 'Err.Raise documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/raise-method if you're curious but hopefully you won't need it.
End Sub
```

I couldn't (and per StackOverflow guidelines shouldn't) do it all for you because I'm not sure what you need `DoMatchFound` to do, and I haven't debugged this, but this gives examples of

- how to get a cell for a given row & column,
- how to get the cell value,
- if-then statements,
- For loops, and
- breaking problems into multiple, smaller problems, each in their own function or subroutine.

Hopefully this will give you a good example of everything you'll need to write `DoMatchFound`.

Programming Advice: Remember to shrug and chip away at the problem! [@mattias-petter-johansson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/304262/mattias-petter-johansson) had a [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCO1cgjhGzsSYb1rsB4bFe4Q) where he said it very well. To paraphrase: *We are problem solvers. Programmers by definition don't know what we're doing... if we did, the solution would be already written and available somewhere.* When "progress" feels like you're bashing your head against the wall only to finally break through and find yourself bashing your head against the next wall, don't get discouraged, just try to find something you haven't tried yet or break the problem down into smaller pieces.

Comment: Thanx for the clue mate.